# How to add a vertical dashed line into table?

Tags: tables, line

I need to draw a table in Latex with a dashed line between the columns Dep and No Coda. I've tried with arydshln, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{qtree}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2cm,includefoot]{geometry} \linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|cc|cc}
   & /weroh/  & {\sc Dep} & {\sc No Coda} & {\sc Max} & {\sc Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & we.roh   &     & *W & L   &       \\
\leftpointright & we.ro    &     &    & *   &       \\
   & we.ro.hi & *W  &    & L   &       \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & /arum/   & {\sc Dep} & {\sc No Coda} & {\sc Max} & {\sc Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & a.rum    &     & *W & L   & *     \\
\leftpointright & a.ru     &     &    & *   & *     \\
   & ru       &     &    & **W & L     \\
   & a.ru.mi  & *W  &    & L   & *     \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & /maur/   & {\sc Dep} & {\sc No Coda} & {\sc Max} & {\sc Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & maur     &     & *W & L   &       \\
\leftpointright& mau      &     &    & *   &       \\
   & mau.ri   & *W  &    & L   &       \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & /afit/   & {\sc Dep} & {\sc No Coda} & {\sc Max} & {\sc Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
   & a.fit    &     & *W & L   & *     \\
\leftpointright & a.fi     &     &    & *   & *     \\
   & fi       &     &    & **W & L     \\
   & a.fi.ti  & *W  &    & L   & *    
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tableau According to the Rough Ranking}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at the `arraydshln` package.

Comment: The name of the package is `arydshln` and not `arraydshln`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You wrote,

> I've tried with `arydshln`, but it doesn't work.

Not sure what you tried, but the following does work.

[image]

Some additional comments and suggestions:

- Don't use the plain-TeX `\sc` directive in a LaTeX document; use `\textsc` instead.
- Don't modify the low-level command `\linespread` directly. Instead, load the `setspace` package and issue a `\setstetch` directive.
- Don't use the nearly-obsolete `times` package. If you need Times Roman as your text font, load a newer package such as `newtxtext`.
- To give the table a slightly more open look, I set the length parameter `\extrarowheight` to `2pt`.
- I can't help but remark that it makes no sense to load the `apacite` package without issuing the directive `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` as well.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{qtree}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

%%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,left=2cm,includefoot]{geometry} 

%%\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{apacite} % <-- make sure this is really needed

\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}

\usepackage{arydshln} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|c:c|cc}\cline{2-6} 
                & /weroh/  & \textsc{Dep} & \textsc{No Coda} & \textsc{Max}  & \textsc{Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & we.roh   &     & *W & L   &       \\
\leftpointright & we.ro    &     &    & *   &       \\
                & we.ro.hi & *W  &    & L   &       \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & /arum/   & \textsc{Dep} & \textsc{No Coda} & \textsc{Max} & \textsc{Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & a.rum    &     & *W & L   & *     \\
\leftpointright & a.ru     &     &    & *   & *     \\
                & ru       &     &    & **W & L     \\
                & a.ru.mi  & *W  &    & L   & *     \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & /maur/   & \textsc{Dep} & \textsc{No Coda} & \textsc{Max} & \textsc{Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & maur     &     & *W & L   &       \\
\leftpointright & mau      &     &    & *   &       \\
                & mau.ri   & *W  &    & L   &       \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & /afit/   & \textsc{Dep} & \textsc{No Coda} & \textsc{Max} & \textsc{Onset} \\ \cline{2-6} 
                & a.fit    &     & *W & L   & *     \\
\leftpointright & a.fi     &     &    & *   & *     \\
                & fi       &     &    & **W & L     \\
                & a.fi.ti  & *W  &    & L   & *     \\ \cline{2-6} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tableau According to the Rough Ranking}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comments and suggestions!

Comment: I've changed my preamble as the one you have here, and it works! Thanks!